# Visual Studio 2015 TFS checks out all the projects in the solution

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

after switching to VS2015 for some reason every time somebody changes project location (moves to other folder) or rename's a project name the VS check outs all the projects in the solution on the TFS, considering there is about 300 projects in the solution it creates a serious problem. anyone encountered that issue? any idea what is causing it?

Comment: No, but I'm not sure what you mean by "checks out"? Does it pend changes or just check them out? Does `tfpt uu /noget /recursive` undo the changes? Are you still using Server Workspaces or local workspaces?

Comment: What I usually do when visual studio checks out a file I think it shouldn't is immediately do a compare between the workspace version and the version that is in TFS.  A lot of times this will tell you why Visual Studio is doing it.  Take a look at the diff and report back here.

Comment: Cole, I did compared it, has no changes,